# Cython define the void function base c++ header

Tags: python, c++, cython

some part of my c++ header file:

```cpp
virtual void OnFrontDisconnected(int nReason){};
```

some declaration of my .pxd file:

```
void OnFrontDisconnected(int nReason) except +
```

about my .pyx files code:

```
cpdef void OnFrontDisconnected(self, int nReason) except +:
    self._this_md_spi.OnFrontDisconnected(nReason)
```

but when I try to compile the code, but i got some errors:
`Cannot convert 'void' to Python object`
`Return with value in void function`

I didn't provide the `return` in code.

Should I to remove the `void` keyword in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't have a `void` return with `cpdef`; Python callers need something back and `void` is not `None`. Just leave off the return value and the appropriate return will be given.

But then note that you have a bigger underlying problem. By writing

```
# In your case, CType == void, but would have
# to be something convertible like int in order
# for it to compile.
cpdef CType function() except +:
    other_function() # also except +
```

you have *disabled all proper error handling!*

The `except +` in the inner function will convert its C++ exception to a Python exception. When the Python exception is thrown in `function`, **this will not be found** as it's only looking for C++ exceptions. You should either do:

```
cpdef CType function() except +:
    other_function() # NOT except +
```

or

```
cpdef CType function() except *:
    other_function() # except +
```

or

```
cpdef function():
    other_function() # except +
```

The third is because not specifying a return type gives it a Python return type, which is automatically dealt with properly.

---

I bet you didn't expect it to be this complex ;).